# Promedio de cada fila en lenguaje c

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, array-bidimensional, matriz, lenguaje-compilado

Me mandan a realizar un código en Lenguaje C que dice:

> En una línea de taxis la cual trabaja de lunes a domingo, existen 6 >taxistas, se necesita llevar el control de las carreras que hace cada taxista >cada día, para ello se manejan los datos en una matriz y hacer lo siguiente:
>
> - Cargar de valores la matriz
> - Contar cuántas veces no se hizo carrera
> - Sacar promedio de carreras por semana

Realizo la matriz pero no sé cómo contar los 0 ni el promedio semanal, puedo sacar el promedio del mes pero no por semana igual con los 0.

```
#include<locale.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Spanish");
    
    int matriz[6][7], fila, columna, cont=0;
    float prom;
    
    for(fila=0; fila<6; fila++){
        for(columna=0; columna<7; columna++){
            printf("Taxista %d, Día de la semana %d, digite las carreras hechas: ", fila+1, columna+1);
            scanf("%d", &matriz[fila][columna]);
                    
            if(matriz[fila][columna]<1){   //Para ir contando los 0
                cont=cont+1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    printf("\n\n");
    
    
    for(fila=0; fila<6; fila++){   //Para mostrar todo lo que se ingresó a la matriz
        for(columna=0; columna<7; columna++){
            printf("%d  ", matriz[fila][columna]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    printf("\nEn total no se hicieron %i carreras", cont);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sin ver un [mcve], será bastante difícil ayudarte. Por favor, coloca el código **como texto**. No tienes mas que [edit] tu pregunta.

Comment: ¿Te da algún error? ¿Cuál es tu pregunta/problema en específico?

Answer (score 1):

> no sé cómo contar los 0

Los pasos son sencillos:

- Declara una variable entera que usarás para llevar la cuenta
- Itera por la matriz
- En cada iteración, comprueba el valor de la celda, si es 0, incrementas el contador

Dicho con código:

```
for( int taxista=0; taxista<6; taxista++ )
{
  int total = 0;
  for( int dia=0; dia<7; dia++ )
  {
    total += (matriz[taxista][dia] == 0); // <<--- 1
  }
  printf("El taxista %d no hizo carreras durante %d dias\n", taxista, total);
}
```

Respecto al comentario que he puesto en el código:

```
total += (matriz[taxista][dia] == 0); // <<--- 1
```

Lo que hacemos aquí es aprovechar una característica del lenguaje. Las operaciones booleanas generan un valor entero que puede valer `0` (falso) o `1` (verdadero). Como nos interesa conocer el total de *verdaderos*, aprovechamos ese 1 para ir llevando el conteo.

> puedo sacar el promedio del mes pero no por semana igual con los 0

Esto que dices es mentira por tres razones:

- No tienes los datos del mes, luego dificilmente vas a poder calcular el promedio de un mes
- El promedio de un mes, de poder calcularse, incorporaría los `0` que dices que te dan problemas en el promedio semanal... si puedes con el del mes, el semanal es igual pero con menos días
- Los promedios son insensibles a los 0...

> ni el promedio semanal

El promedio se calcula así:

- Declara una variable entera que usarás de acumulador
- Itera por la matriz
- En cada iteración, acumula en la variable el valor de la celda
- Una vez has terminado las iteraciones, divide el valor del acumulador entre el número total de valores (en este caso 7).

Es decir, si un taxista presenta los siguientes valores:

```
5 0 3 7 0 0 9
```

El promedio sería:

```
(5 + 0 + 3 + 7 + 0 + 0 + 9) / 7 = 3
```

Espera... ¿y no da decimales?

Para obtener un resultado con decimales tienes que usar un tipo de dato que sea capaz de almacenar decimales (y no, `int` no vale). Una operación entre dos `int` descarta automáticamente cualquier decimal que se pudiese generar. Tienes que *promocionar* alguno de los valores involucrados en la operación a un tipo decimal para que la operación te devuelva decimales:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 2;

printf("%d %f", a/b, a/(float)b);
```

> ¿Y no pones código?

En este caso no, lo siento. Tu comentario respecto a los promedios me ha sonado a "*me gustaría que alguien me hiciese la tarea*" y yo, si quieres, te hago los deberes... pero entonces te tendría que cobrar por ello ya que te estaría dedicando mi tiempo en exclusiva a ti en vez de escribir respuestas que le sirviesen a más gente.